HighCharts: Bell Curve - how to add deviation percentage areas
This is a simple 'bellcurve' chart: jsfiddle
    series: [{
    name: 'Bell curve',
    type: 'bellcurve',
    xAxis: 1,
    yAxis: 1,
    baseSeries: 1,
    zIndex: -1
}, {
    name: 'Data',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: data,
    accessibility: {
        exposeAsGroupOnly: true
    },
    marker: {
        radius: 1.5
    }
}]


Question: How is it possible to highlight with HighCharts the areas of deviation (percentage: 2.35%, 13.5%, 34%) ?
Example:


It can be done by using the zones feature and setting the series.zoneAxis to 'x'.
API reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bellcurve.zones
Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3tjku69r/
  zoneAxis: "x",
  zones: [
    {
      value: 2.18,
      color: "rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.25)",
    },
    {
      value: 2.62,
      color: "rgb(0, 102, 255, 0.25)",
    },
    {
      value: 3.49,
      color: "rgb(51, 204, 51, 0.25)",
    },
    {
      value: 3.92,
      color: "rgb(0, 102, 255, 0.25)",
    },
    {
      color: "rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.25)",
    }
  ]


Thanks Dominik! But the values are hardcoded.. was looking for something dynamic.. based on percentage, for example: [2.35%, 13.5%. 34%]

Are you asking about calculating the percentage of the bell curve's x-axis data range? You can compute this dynamically within the chart.events.load function, for example. However, I assume you're no longer referring to the x-coordinates of the bell curve itself, correct?
